# Using multiple parameters in URL, params between static url are not available

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am using express.js (v 4.13.4), node.js (v 0.12.5) and body-parser (v 1.13.2) to create a simple chat RESTful API.

I have this url path which must be called by the user:
`http://myhost/chat/room/:roomId/message/:messageId`

Body-parser is set like this:

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I am unable to read the first url parameter `:roomId` but the `:messageId` is available.
I am accessing those parameters using `req.params.roomId` and `req.params.messageId` in request callback function.

Question:

1. Is it wrong to have parameters in the middle of a url?
2. Why would the application not parse `:roomId`?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters roomId and so are send as query parameter therefore req.params.roomId is required to fetch.

Another way to do is send params as body, that way URL will be clean and then to access params body-parser is required.
To send params in body, create a post request through postman and specify params there.[refer this for sending params in body](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/02/20/using-variables-inside-postman-and-collection-runner/)

Answer (score 0):

It is working in my case.

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/chat/room/:roomId/message/:messageId', function(req, res){
   console.log('Room Id: '+req.params.roomId);
   console.log('Message Id: '+req.params.messageId);

   res.sendStatus(200);
});


app.listen(3000);
```

Now, if I try to access `localhost:3000/chat/room/1/message/100`, I get

```
Room Id: 1
Message Id: 100
```

Please check the spelling of **roomId**. May be typo can be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers Mukesh Sharma and Himani Agrawal.
I found the issue now, here it is:

If I register a room router like this:

```
var RoomRouter = express.Router();

RoomRouter.get('/:roomId/message/:messageId', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Room Id: '+req.params.roomId);
  console.log('Message Id: '+req.params.messageId);
  res.status(200);
  res.send("Ok");
});

app.use('/chat/room', RoomRouter);
```

`:roomId` and `:messageId` are received accordingly.

But if I register the room router like this (as it was when I posted the error) `:roomId` is not available.

```
var RoomRouter = express.Router();

RoomRouter.get('/message/:messageId', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Room Id: '+req.params.roomId);
  console.log('Message Id: '+req.params.messageId);
  res.status(200);
  res.send("Ok");
});

app.use('/chat/room/:roomId', RoomRouter);
```

This was my issue, I don't know exactly why the url would be parsed differently in two different situation but I am sure this has a logic somewhere.